# Which name space is the Iterator class in?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

In the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Where.cs) for `System.Linq.Enumerable.Where` method, at line 25 there is the following:

```
if (source is Iterator<TSource> iterator)
```

I can't find what the class `Iterator` is. Which name space is it in?

Comment: It's an internal abstract class nested inside class `Enumerable`.

Comment: `Iterator.cs` is in the same directory as that file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use https://source.dot.net to browse the .NET Core source (and https://referencesource.microsoft.com to browse the .NET Framework source).

Your method [is here](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/Where.cs,13). You can click on `Iterator<T>` and it takes you [here](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/Iterator.cs,00f3550fbfefd123), in `System/Linq/Iterator.cs`, in the `System.Linq` namespace. It's an internal type used by `Enumerable`.